# Cómo recorrer un arreglo de objetos con arreglos anidados en Angular

Tags: array, typescript, objeto

Tengo unos datos estructurados de la siguiente forma:

```js
datos = 
  [
    {0:
      'carlos','1':
      [
        {
          'id': 112,
          'fecha': '20/08/11'
        },
        {
          'id': 113,
          'fecha': '20/08/11'
        }
      ]
    },
    {1:
      'jose','2':
      [
        {
          'id': 114,
          'fecha': '20/09/11'
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
```

Estoy intentando recorrer en el `html` estos datos, estoy intentando mostrar los datos `id` y `fecha`, pero no se muy bien como hacerlo, he estado intentando esto:

```html
<div *ngFor ="let item of datos | keyvalue"  >
  {{item.key}}  {{item.value}}
</div>
```

Pero me devuelve esto:

```js
0 [object Object]
1 [object Object]
```

Que obviamente está mal, cómo podría recorrer los datos hasta llegar a mostrar la información. Agradezco si alguien me podría ayudar o guiar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Una forma de iterarlos es creando una función para obtener la clave de una posición determinada. para obtener el valor `carlos` sería `Object.keys(obj)[0];`

*La función tiene el tipo any, pero sería bueno extraer esto en una interface.*

```
public getKeyByPosition(obj: any,position=0): any{
    return Object.keys(obj)[position];
}
```

La vista podría quedar así.

```
<div *ngFor="let item of datos;index as i">
    <p>{{item[getKeyByPosition(item)]}}</p>
    <p *ngFor="let dataItem of item[getKeyByPosition(item,1)]"  >
      {{dataItem.id}} {{dataItem.fecha}}
    </p>
```

[`DEMO ONLINE`](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-jnuo5t)

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta amigo, una pregunta, cómo puedo hacer para mostrar las dos key, por ejemplo tengo  `'carlos','1'` ,` 'jose','2'`, con tu respuesta se muestra actualmente carlos y jose,  pero en caso de que necesite mostrar las otras key que son 1 y 2 cómo podría hacer? Gracias!